# Filter rows based on field text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to get the sum of all values in column B for which column A equals to 'Lorem'. The result should be 15.

```
   A      B
1. Lorem    5
2. Lorem    5
3. Ipsum  100
4. Lorem    5
```

Tried the following formule, but get the error: `Formula parse error.`

```
=SUM(FILTER(B1:B4,A1:A4='Lorem'))
```

Here is the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11NlGbdzUlkjpQqPVfTncC17nXqRVCLHCvpDsk5NVZuc/edit?usp=sharing) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes around the string.

```
=SUM(FILTER(B1:B4,A1:A4="Lorem"))
```

Alternative ways would be..

```
=SUMIF(A1:A4, "Lorem", B1:B4)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4="Lorem", B1:B4)
```